# Building SpatialPolygonsDataFrame - Error: Object length mismatch

Tags: gis, geospatial, polygon, spatial

I'm trying to make a spatial grid of 400 squares (20x20) each 0.5 degrees in length. I have successfully made a SpatialPolygons object, using the workflow suggested by '?SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' (i.e. Polygon > Polygons > SpatialPolygons > SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). Even though there are 400 elements in the SpatialPolygons object, at the final stage of appending data ('coords' object) R comes back with the error

```
Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(grid, coords) : Object length mismatch:
 grid has 1 Polygons objects, but coords has 400 rows
```

The goal is to append different attribute data to this grid to display various environmental variables. In this example I want to simply re-append coordinate data, but this problem persisted irrespective of the information I was trying to combine. Why does the SpatialPolygon only have 1 object? Full code is available here.

```
lat=c(rep(-10,20),rep(-10.5,20),rep(-11,20),rep(-11.5,20),rep(-12,20),rep(-12.5,20),rep(-13,20),rep(-13.5,20),rep(-14,20),rep(-14.5,20),
  rep(-15,20),rep(-15.5,20),rep(-16,20),rep(-16.5,20),rep(-17,20),rep(-17.5,20),rep(-18,20),rep(-18.5,20),rep(-19,20),rep(-19.5,20))
lon=rep(c(0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2,-2.5,-3,-3.5,-4,-4.5,-5,-5.5,-6,
      -6.5,-7,-7.5,-8,-8.5,-9,-9.5), 20)
coords=cbind(lon, lat)
coords=as.data.frame(coords)
coords$latlon=paste(coords$lat,coords$lon)
coords$latlon=factor(coords$latlon)

f=vector('list',400)
result=vector('list',400)

for (i in 1:length(f)) {
temp = matrix(c(coords[i,2], coords[i,1],
              coords[i,2], coords[i,1]+0.5,
              coords[i,2]+0.5, coords[i,1]+0.5,
              coords[i,2]+0.5, coords[i,1]),
            ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
result[[i]] = Polygon(temp)
rm(temp)
}

grid = Polygons(result, ID = 'a')
grid = SpatialPolygons(list(grid), proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'))
grid = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(grid, coords) #WHY DOESN'T THIS FINAL STEP WORK!!??
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your step `grid = Polygons(result, ID = 'a')` is *collapsing* your polygons from 400 to 1 and this is causing a length mismatch.

Does this code produce the expected result?

```
grid <- lapply(seq_along(result), function(x){
  Polygons(result[x], ID = (1:length(result))[x])
  })
grid <- SpatialPolygons(grid, proj4string = CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'))
grid <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(grid, coords)
```

You might have better luck getting a response if you tag your question with the `sp` package or `R`.